# Xamarin.mac mouse events not working in OxyPlot

Tags: c#, xamarin.mac, oxyplot

I use Xamarin Studio 6.3 with Xamarin.Mac. I want to always show tracking info in OzyPlot.PlotView. I have try to use PlotModel.TrackerChanged, PlotModel.MouseMove, CandleStickSeries.MouseMove and other events. PlotModel.TrackerChanged never happened, CandleStickSeries.MouseMove have happen only when left mouse button down and move.
How can I catch events? In the GTK# all fine.

I use this code of ViewController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AppKit;
using Foundation;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Mac;

namespace OxyPlotTest
{
    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        List<HighLowItem> bars;

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            bars = new List<HighLowItem>();

            PlotView plotView = new PlotView(viewCtrl.Frame);

            PlotModel model = new PlotModel { };

            model.TrackerChanged += OnTrackerChanged;
            model.MouseMove += onSeriesMouseMove;

            model.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
                MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
            });

            model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
                MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
            });

            CandleStickSeries cs = new CandleStickSeries()
            {
                IncreasingFill = OxyColors.DarkGreen,
                DecreasingFill = OxyColors.Red,
                DataFieldX = "X",
                DataFieldHigh = "High",
                DataFieldLow = "Low",
                DataFieldOpen = "Open",
                DataFieldClose = "Close",
                TrackerFormatString = "High: {2:0.00}\nLow: {3:0.00}\nOpen: {4:0.00}\nClose: {5:0.00}",
                ItemsSource = bars

            };

            cs.MouseMove += OnCSMouseMove;

            model.Series.Add(cs);
            plotView.Model = model;

            viewCtrl.AddSubview(plotView);

            bars.Add(new HighLowItem(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now), 10, 2, 5, 8));
            bars.Add(new HighLowItem(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)), 15, 6, 8, 11));
            bars.Add(new HighLowItem(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2)), 10, 2, 11, 15));
            bars.Add(new HighLowItem(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3)), 16, 9, 15, 10));
            bars.Add(new HighLowItem(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(4)), 11, 5, 10, 8));
            bars.Add(new HighLowItem(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)), 12, 3, 8, 6));

            plotView.InvalidatePlot();
        }

        void OnCSMouseMove(object sender, OxyMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnCSMouseMove");
        }

        void onSeriesMouseMove(object sender, OxyMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("onSeriesMouseMove");
        }

        void OnTrackerChanged(object sender, TrackerEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnTrackerChanged");
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;
                // Update the view, if already loaded.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dzam, Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Lijo, Hi. My solution was use own ViewController, that catch MouseMove event and call MouseMove of PlotView.